# Автоматическая авторизация на сайте (без моего участия)

Tags: golang

Нужно, чтобы автоматический заходил на GitHub, вводил адрес электронной почты и пароль и авторизовывался, возможно ли это реализовать на Go? Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Посоветую заходить по ключам, а не по паролю. Более безопасно выдать программе ключ, чем оставлять пароль и полные права.

Можно, например, дать доступ к отдельному репозиторию, на чтение, или на запись:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#deploy-keys

Comment: А как это сделать? И с чего начать? Спасибо за ваш ответ

Comment: a что потом программа будет на гитхабе делать?

Comment: ваша ссылка очень полезна, но мне нужно, чтобы именно по адресу эл-почты и паролю авторизовывался

Comment: зачем? это менее безопасно

Comment: да, это небезопасно. Объяснять для чего это нужно очень долго

Comment: ну, если соберетесь, пишите.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Читаем [документацию](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/) и шлем запрос с учётными данными. Как уже было сказано у этого функционала истекает срок годности и он будет заменён на Oauth 2.0 с использованием токенов.

Примерь CURL запроса для авторизации для получения токена [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371032/how-to-get-github-token-using-username-and-password):

`curl -u "user:pwd" https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo`

Заголовок Basic авторизации также есть по ссылке.